# Is there a way to add a "press enter" command in between of chained commands in terminal?

Tags: terminal, git-bash

I have a chain of commands for install some "especial" dependencies (those should not be in my package.json) so I just chain them in this way:

```
npm install depedency1 && npm install depedency2 && npm install depedency3 && ..
```

The thing is there is a couple of them that need user input but that is just press the ENTER Key 5 times for five questions. I would like to include this 5 ENTERs in this command chain so if I left when it is working I can go back and all will be ready and no waiting for me to press enter to make the last step.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hrm. I would suggest piping the output of `yes`, but I'm not sure you can make it output empty lines. I guess you could have `echo` output 5 newlines; I don't have a terminal to test in so I won't post this as an answer.

Comment: you are probably looking for [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).